# Help With Algebraic Properties of 12-sided Regular Polygon with Binary Colorable Vertices

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetry

I'm fairly new to abstract algebra and I stumbled across this problem (in music, actually) involving dihedral symmetries of a dodecagon where the vertices are either filled or unfilled, like in this image:[image] and I'm having trouble figuring out the structure that would describe the collection of groups of symmetries of such objects. Obviously $D_{24}$ is in it, so perhaps the collection of dihedral groups with order less than or equal to 24? How would I prove that? Do I call it a "collection" or something else, like a category?

Comment: That's a dodecagon. A dodecahedron is a solid with 12 faces.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is the set of all *subgroups* of $D_{24}$.

Comment: It might be helpful to take as given the poset of subgroups and try to find, for each subgroup, a configuration whose symmetry group is that subgroup
https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~matyd/GroupNames/1/D12.html